# How to link an array of numbers to another array of numbers?

Tags: python

Im a beginner in python and im currently working on a problem on code forces called Lecture Sleep. The question gives you 3 lines of inputs:

```
6 3
1 3 5 2 5 4
1 1 0 1 0 0
```

I'm trying to figure out how to link the second array of numbers `(1 3 5 2 5 4)` to the 3rd array of numbers `(1 1 0 1 0 0)`. So that `1 = 1, 3 = 1, 5 = 0, 2 = 1, 5 = 0, 4 = 0`.

Comment: What are you planning to do with the array after linking them? Do you want to access the 3rd array's values from a value from the 2nd array?

Comment: For the curious, [here is the original problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/961/B) with a lot of detail that isn't included in this question.

Comment: Can you include examples for what you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

Best I can think of is `zipping` the two together:

```
lst1, lst2 = [1, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4], [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2):
    print("{} = {}".format(x, y))
```

Which yields

```
1 = 1
3 = 1
5 = 0
2 = 1
5 = 0
4 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a dictionary where every item of the first list is the key to the item of the second list:

```
lst1 = [1, 3, 5, 2, 5, 4]

lst2 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

res = dict((zip(lst1, lst2)))

print(res)
#{1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 0, 2: 1, 4: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are needing something called a dictionary.

So if you have the following:

```
li1 = [1,3,5,2,5,4]
li2 = [1,1,0,1,0,0]

mydict = {} #declares dictionary object

for i in range(len(li1)):
    mydict[li1[i]] = li2[i]

print(mydict)
```

gives the following output of the dictionary object:

```
{1: 1, 3: 1, 5: 0, 2: 1, 4: 0}
```

So these numbers are linked together now.